# Is there a way to change the property names to snake_case in an ASP.NET Core 3.0 API?

Tags: c#, rest, api, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm trying to change all the property names to snake_case globally in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 API, but I couldn't find a way.

Previously, in ASP.NET Core 2.2, I used:

```cs
services.AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() })
```

Now in ASP Net Core 3.0 the only thing that I found barely similar was:

```cs
services.AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase)
```

But snake_case is not present.

Is there a such way to make snake_case for the request and response objects globally in my ASP.NET Core 3.0 API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the solution after read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

The new code is:

```
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() })
```

Comment: While the code above does work and will give you the exact same thing as you had before it will also make you use Newtonsoft instead of the System.Text.Json which is faster, async and built in.

Comment: snake_case support in the .NET Core 3.0+ serializer is scheduled for System.Text.Json 5.0: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/39564

Comment: According to that thread snake case support was never added to .Net 5 or 6.

Answer (score 6):

Inspired by the [snakcase_json repository](https://github.com/michaelrosedev/snakecase_json) a simple, but potentially not very efficient solution would be:

```cs
public class SnakeCasePropertyNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        return string.Concat(name.Select((character, index) =>
                index > 0 && char.IsUpper(character)
                    ? "_" + character
                    : character.ToString()))
            .ToLower();
    }
}
```

And then in the startup add the follow options:

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCasePropertyNamingPolicy();
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

For .NET Core 3.0, use:

```
 .AddJsonOptions(o => o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null)
```

Comment: This removes any naming policy and doesn't enforce a snake_case. However it will allow you to pass-through the original property name, so if you use snake_case for the property, it will be serialized correctly. As such this is more a workaround than a solution.